# Flink: java.io.NotSerializableException: redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster

Tags: java, apache-flink, jedis

When I submit new flink job, it throws

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:512)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:81)
    ... 24 more
```

this is my code:

```
    JedisCluster jedisCluster = JedisClusterBuilder.getInstance(JedisClusterEnum.THIRD);


    DataStream<MobileClickEvent> clickEventDataStream = environment.addSource(clickConsumer);


    clickEventDataStream
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .keyBy(new KeySelector<MobileClickEvent, String>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(MobileClickEvent value) throws Exception {
                    return value.getItemId() + "_" + value.getItemType();
                }
            })
            .process(new KeyedProcessFunction<String, MobileClickEvent, Object>() {
                @Override
                public void processElement(MobileClickEvent value, Context ctx, Collector<Object> out) throws Exception {
                    String key = ctx.getCurrentKey();
                    jedisCluster.hincrBy("{item_feature}" + key, "click", 1);
                    jedisCluster.expire("{item_feature}" + key, 60 * 10);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56057507/3788176), `jedisCluster` will be initialized for each element.

Consider overriding [`open`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RichFunction.html#open-org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration-) as well, and initialize there.

> Initialization method for the function. It is called before the actual working methods (like map or join) and thus suitable for one time setup work.

```
.process(new KeyedProcessFunction<String, MobileClickEvent, Object>() {
    private JedisCluster jedisCluster;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        jedisCluster = JedisClusterBuilder.getInstance(JedisClusterEnum.THIRD);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(MobileClickEvent value, Context ctx, Collector<Object> out) throws Exception {
        String key = ctx.getCurrentKey();
        jedisCluster.hincrBy(REDIS_PREFIX + key, "click", 1);
        jedisCluster.expire(REDIS_PREFIX + key, 60 * 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I will try it latter